# AttributeError: 'Serializer' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i have created this serializer to validate on the presence of a record with these column combination`

```
class CampaignServicesValidation(serializers.Serializer):
    campaign_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    service_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        try:
            campaign_service = CampaignServices.objects.get(campaign_id=data['campaign_id'],
                                                            service_id=data['service_id'])
            print("found"+str(campaign_service.id))
        except Exception:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(detail='Campaign Service does not exist')
        return campaign_service
```

and it is called in my viewSet like this:

```
campaign_service = CampaignServicesValidation(data={'campaign_id': request.data['campaign_id'], 'service_id': pk})
        if not campaign_service.is_valid():
            return RestResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, serializer_error=campaign_service.errors)
```

when the combination is not found it raises an exception and works well, but when it passes validation and enters the `is_valid()` function in the if condition it produces this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\RightsHero\collector-management\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\RightsHero\collector-management\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\RightsHero\collector-management\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\RightsHero\collector-management\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\RightsHero\collector-management\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "D:\RightsHero\collector-management\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "D:\RightsHero\collector-management\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "D:\RightsHero\collector-management\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\RightsHero\collector-management\collectors_management\views.py", line 157, in update_campaign_service_frequency
    serializer.save()
  File "D:\RightsHero\collector-management\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 207, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "D:\RightsHero\collector-management\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 993, in update
    info = model_meta.get_field_info(instance)
  File "D:\RightsHero\collector-management\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\model_meta.py", line 35, in get_field_info
    opts = model._meta.concrete_model._meta
AttributeError: 'CampaignServicesValidation' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I have tried changing serializer.Serializer to ModelSerialzier but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Since Serializer does not have a **_meta** attribute, it does not have the **is_valid()** method. Instead, you should check the **serializer.errors** attribute of the serializer after calling **validate()**.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. However, i did try using the `validate()` method and it still produced the same error.